# Instagram api sandbox

Tags: api, instagram, sandbox

I today get Instagram api and add my website live,
I see write:

Client Status: **Sandbox Mode** GO LIVE

I can't click on ''GO LIVE'' button why ?

Comment: I see sandbox mean ''instagram team need check my app'' how i can contact instagram team for see what i need edit on my app for go live ?

Comment: I have the same problem, Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to start a submission for approval to go live, though:

Feeds for websites won't be approved; these will remain in sandbox mode and be limited to 500 requests per hour and 20 images. This doesn't sound like much especially for large clients, but if you cache your responses, it's not a problem.

The main confusion is because they have made it sound like every app/feed has to be approved and out of sandbox mode to work, where as the reality is that only fully functioning apps for phones, or a widget plugin really ever need to be.

You will no longer be able to display feeds based on hashtags, only a users own photo's. By getting a client to be a sandbox user, is how you can access their feed without their login information.

Older apps/feeds will need to be updated to use the new code before June or they may stop working.

It's mainly to stop apps hammering instagram's servers for unlimited requests on any hashtag/users they like.

Here is an example of how to fetch and cache images using WordPress's 'set_transient' - you will need to use a loop to output the data.
[WordPress Instagram Gist](https://gist.github.com/callamwilliams/981fc04b9bb2f4efaf34)

Here is the relevant piece of information in the dev docs:

**Here are some examples of scenarios that will not be approved:**

- To display content for a personal website. **If you are a developer and you want to showcase Instagram content on a website, then you do not need to submit your app for review**. By using a client in sandbox mode, you will still be able to access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you permission.
- One-off projects. If you are an agency building websites or other integrations, note that we don't grant permissions to clients created for one-off projects. If you are interested in building a product, platform, or widget that will be used as a service across multiple projects, then you may submit a single client_id that you can use across multiple projects.
- To use a widget. If you are installing a widget for your website, then you do not need to submit for review. Some widgets may ask you to create a new client id, but you do not need to submit it for review for the widget to work. Your client can remain in sandbox mode and the widget will have access to your last 20 media.

Hope that helps clear some confusion.

Comment: " If you are a developer and you want to showcase Instagram content on a website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you will still be able to access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you permission." how? use it in place of the access_token? If I need to generate an access token I still need to login. and I want to login on behalf of the client I'm showcasing

Comment: You need to [log in](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) to your developer account, go to 'manage clients' select client then the 'sandbox tab', and invite the account whos content you want to display. They will then have to log in and accept this invitation for you to access their content. You would then generate an access token based on your account details and it will be able to access their images.

Comment: but when that access token expires you break the site (possibly) and you have to manually generate a new one. that's just plain stupid

Comment: That token shouldn't expire. The token is linked to your own account and won't change  unless you change your email/password. As long as the client keeps sandbox access to your app enabled you will still be able to access their images. The bad bit is that it's limited to 10 clients which for a freelancer is going to get frustrating - my agency had to develop a custom app just to get public access approved